# How does Delphi web-services work ? ( Adding method in runtime ?? )

Tags: web-services, delphi, interface, runtime

I've created web-service in Delphi XE using WSDL importer.
Delphi generated for me module ITransmitter1.pas with
ITransmitter interface and GetITransmitter function.

To use webservice i use:

```
var Transmitter: ITransmitter;
begin
  Transmitter := GetITransmitter(True, '', nil);
  Transmitter.Transmit(Memo1.Text, OutXML);
end;
```

But i cant see anywhere body of method Transmit ...

In ITransmitter.pas i see:

```
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ITransmitter), 'urn:TransmitterIntf-ITransmitter', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(ITransmitter), 'urn:TransmitterIntf-ITransmitter#Transmit');
```

If i comment this lines i get "interface not supported" error.
As i see here delphi is adding method in RunTime !
How does it work ?  Can i add method in runtime to my own class ?

Answer (score 2):

If you created a web service client with the WSDL importer, the generated client code will invoke a method on the server. So in fact, the method 'body' (code) is on the web service server.

Delphi generates a Soap request based on the WSDL, and behind the scenes RTTI (introspection) is used to generate parameters etc. of the web service call as XML. This XML is sent to the server, which executes the method implementation and sends back a Soap response.

Things are opposite if you create the web service server, in this case the Delphi application of course needs to implement all method bodies.

Comment: I cant debug my Transmitter.Transmit method. And I still wonder which method is in fact executed when i call Transmitter.Transmit?  Usually when i call some method , i see code placed in some .pas file. Now i have no idea what actually happens when i call this method ...

Answer (score 1):

You're in fact calling a *method* defined in a Interface, which in turn inherits from IInvokable, declared in System.pas.

If you check your source code you'll note that no local object in your project implements the IInvokable interface you're calling, that's because that method is remotely executed in the server.

Before that occurs, there's some pascal code used to create a proper SOAP request to the server, send it and then wait and interpret the server response, consider this implementation details.  If you're interested in know a bit more how this works, enable the "use debug .dcus" compiler option, so you can debug inside the VCL/RTL.

Then, as usual, use the StepInto (F7) command to ask the debugger to execute the Transmit method step by step... after some assembler in the TRIO.GenericStub method you'll get to the TRIO.Generic method where the packet is prepared and sent.

For a btSOAP binding I'm using to write this response, the relevant part starts at line 943 in the Rio.pas unit:

```
    try
      FWebNode.Execute(Req, Resp);
    finally
      { Clear Outbound headers }
      FHeadersOutBound.Clear;
    end;
```

THTTPReqResp.Execute then uses wininet.dll functions to perform the connection, send and receive of information with the server using.

There are some levels you can go deep with this... how far you want to go will depend on your interests and the great amount of details are far beyond the scope of my answer here... feel free to post more questions with specific tings you're interested in.

I'm not sure about, but details can change between Delphi versions... I'm using Delphi XE right now.

Comment: OK. What i see is : Transmitter object was generated by GetITTransmitter function. This function generates result this way : RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil); Result := (RIO as ITransmitter); So reallisation of method Transmit should be in THTTPRIO class. But as i see there is not one. So as i understand whenever i call any method of Transmitter, no matter which, in fact TRIO.GenericStub will be executed. So can i make my own class with this future? I meen such class, so no matter which method i call, anyway delphi will call some fixed method  ?

Comment: @Astronavigator: ITransmitter is a interface generated by Delphi while processing the WDSL by the WDSL importer.  In short the Generic method is invoked for any interface method you call. There's no actual object where that method is defined at client side: the interface is defined for your convenience, you can interact with the web service the same way you do with other objects in your application. The THTTPRio/TRio classes use the standard QueryInterface method that is invoked while the AS operator cast the object to a Interface to generate a VTable on the fly to perform that mapping.

Comment: Take a look at the TRio.GenVTable method, which is called while processing the QueryInterface.  The unit is soap\Rio.pas